# How to split long email to fit in a column on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm displayng emails in a quite narrow column with some other data. In most cases emails fit into the column width but sometimes if an email is long it doesn'r fit and doesn't look nice.
Is there a way (may be jquery method) or something like this to split email (to make it look like this):

```
this_is_a_long_email
@some_domain.net
```

I probably can write some javascript for it but don't want to invent a bicicle if it already exists (I tried to search but didn't find anything).

Thanks

Comment: So I understand that you have written a e-mail client or what?

Comment: Are you simply asking how to make it wrap to fit in the available width, or are you asking specifically how to make it wrap at the `@`?

Comment: @mugur, no, sorry if it's not clear here. I's just a simple html page which displays someone's profile and their email from db. Email is a single word with no spaces inside so browser won't split it to 2 lines. My intent to do it manually.

Comment: Setting column width to auto should work.

Comment: @thirtydot preferable to wrap at the `@` , if there is an easy way to wrap it to fit some width it might also work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @thirtydot preferable to wrap at the @ , if there is an easy way to
>   wrap it to fit some width it might also work

Making it just wrap is really easy. Add [`word-wrap: break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap) to the containing element.

To make it *prefer* to wrap at `@`, you'll also need to insert a `&#8203;` ([Zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)) before the `@`, ideally using your server-side language.

```
<span style="word-wrap: break-word">this_is_a_long_email&#8203;@some_domain.net</span>
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I need, thanks! thanks to all other guys who answered as well!

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmDwH/)

HTML:

```
<span class="MailPart">this_is_a_long_email</span><span class="MailPart">@some_domain.net</span>
```

CSS:

```
.MailPart{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery to do this.  CSS will do it wonderfully (however not particular at the @ sign though)

`<div class="breakWord">this_is_a_long_email@some_domain.net</div>`

```
.breakWord
{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Or

`<div style="word-wrap: break-word;">this_is_a_long_email@some_domain.net</div>`

Comment: Not really @Sergio.  Inline CSS is the master of all and overrides anything else in the CSS cascading hierarchy.  Here is the order processed:  1) Browser defaults 2) External style sheets 3) Internal style sheets 4) inline style.  Being last, it makes it override anything before it.  :)  Happy coding!!

Comment: Ok, but if you use this a lot, can be a pain to maintain, right? :)

Comment: Dude, I'm not going to argue with you. The time it takes to open a file for editing from source control, modifying it, and then saving back into source control is just the same regardless of if the extension is .css or .html.

Answer (score 1):

```
var emailadd = forename.surame@improbablylongwebdomain.com;
```

A quick and dirty would be to replace the `@` with `@<br/>` to force it to break onto two lines.

```
emailadd = emailadd.replace ('@', '<br />@');
```

You could do this when the part after the '@' is longer than needs to be to fit in your layout.

Comment: this will also break short emails which perfectly and nicely fit in one line

Comment: "You could do this when the part after the '@' is longer than needs to be to fit in your layout."

Reading the entire response carefully and using a little intelligence and initiative often prevents people posting silly comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use word-wrap for this.

Here's a dabblet showing how to do it:

http://dabblet.com/gist/1789487